# How to diagnose "Drain" not working properly in IIS with ARR?

Tags: asp.net, iis, arr

I have an ASP.NET website, and a blue/green setup in IIS with ARR, and as part of my deployment process I'm setting one of the servers to "Drain". The problem is that as soon as the server goes into drain mode, the page just resets to the other server - so if I'm signed in to a page like, "my account", and it's on the green server, as soon as I switch the green server to drain, and then refresh the page, it immediately will pull up the page from the blue server, but then also not know that I'm signed in, and will redirect me back to the sign in page as if I was never on the site.

My searches for this issue are met with lots of really great tutorials, but they all assume that the drain function will keep existing pages/connections on the old version until plenty of time passes (like an hour) or they close out the page that is using the old version.

How do I figure out why drain is not working properly, and how would I fix it so that it does?

Comment: Since IIS and ARR does not by default provide a blue/green setup, it is your responsibility to ask such a question with enough details on what extra configuration you did (in case you chose a setup with limitation at the very beginning). Personally I don't think merely IIS/ARR can give true blue/green, and people should use more suitable enablers like Kubernetes, https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/04/30/zero-downtime-deployment-kubernetes-jenkins/

Comment: It may difficult to find out reason. But what about try to store login information in database, then no matter which backend server you switch in, you can read the login information from the database.